# Visual Studio Code - unable to attach debugger to remote Node.js application

Tags: visual-studio-code

here is my debug configuration :

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "testServer",
    "address": "test.server.ip",
    "port": 5858,
    "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/test/server",
    "remoteRoot": "~/App/test/server"
}
```

I have started remote application in debug mode successfully by using below command

```
node --debug app
```

Then I start VS Code debugger using testServer configuration. it print error:

```
Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js version could not be determined (Error: timeout)
```

I am using **VS Code version 1.16.1 on macOS sierra.**

I guess it's not able to connect remote server because it's secured by SSH. But I can't see any configuration related to SSH in VS Code debugger's configuration.

I have already gone through some [articles](https://medium.com/@dakshika/remote-debug-node-js-application-using-visual-studio-code-dc0fa0b4dec4) and issues like [this](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/487)
 and[this](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Debugging:-Remote-Debuging), but no help.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start the remote application, and tell node to expose the port remotely with the following command:

```
node app --inspect=0.0.0.0:5858
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like that on Windows :

Create a new putty session with hostname, your remote server, and go to "Tunnels" under the SSH dropdown, then configure it like it :

Run node debug on your remote host and copy the port it give to you (For me 9229)

[Run node debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxSDR.png)

Then fill Putty like that :

[Fill putty tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbXn4.png)

You can now save this session, and then open it.
 Now, every time you will open this SSH session, everything happening on your remote server on port 9229 will be redirected to your local 9229 port.

In VSCode, the config is now really simple, because it's like you are on local :

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach",
        "port": 9229
    },
```

Hope it helped